# send cookies in hyperlink

Tags: html, cookies, hyperlink, tags

I want to send cookies with the hyperlink

sample

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">hello</a>
```

Cookie("location_ID", "NEWYork", google.com, "/",false , 0);

I have many dynamics to be sent with different hyperlinks

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" id="mylink" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">hello</a>
```

jQuery

```
$("a#mylink").bind("click", function() {
    $.cookie("location_ID", "NEWYork", google.com, "/",false , 0);
});
```